# How do I alert multiple results of a callback from an arrow function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can alert a single result from a callback but don't know how to structure my code for multiple results.

I've returned a string from my extendscript file with success but when I try to return an object or an array with multiple strings it errors

```
// THIS WORKS

//// extendscript.jsx
return 'success';


//// main.js
evalExtendscript(`parseProfileDCLVOD(${JSON.stringify(form)})`)
    .then(result => alert(result))  // alerts 'success'
    .catch(error => alert(error))


//---------------------------------------------------


// THIS DOESN'T WORK

//// extendscript.jsx 
var result = {
    variant: 'success',
    message: 'Export successful'
}
return result;


//// main.js
evalExtendscript(`parseProfileDCLVOD(${JSON.stringify(form)})`)
    .then(result => {
        alert(result.variant)  
        alert(result.message)  
    })
    .catch(error => alert(error))
```

I don't think I'm structuring my code for the result correctly.

Comment: Can you input console before call alert(result.variant) and share result?

Comment: What was an error you are facing ?

Comment: @WasiqMuhammad  If I alert(result) I get [object Object] and if I alert(result.message) I get an empty string.

Comment: When I alert(Object.keys(result) the result is:  0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. It was actually a problem in the extendscript.jsx. It was supposed to be:

```
var result = {
    variant: 'success',
    message: 'Export successful'
}
return JSON.stringify(result);
```